# Java/Kotlin: Parse JSON Object bug

Tags: kotlin, org.json

I have a text json that I recover from an API, but I can not decode it, because in the json I have only one object and not several:

```
{  
   "address": "mickaelnanah@gmail.com",
   "username": "mickaelnanah",
   "domain": "gmail.com",
   "md5Hash": "0f6082627bfdeb56a3792f52ce8f0cb8",
   "validFormat": true,
   "deliverable": true,
   "fullInbox": false,
   "hostExists": true,
   "catchAll": false,
   "disposable": false,
   "free": true
}
```

my code:

```
val jsonObj = JSONObject(jSonString.substring(jSonString.indexOf("{"), jSonString.lastIndexOf("}") + 1))
val mail = Email(jsonObj.getJSONObject("deliverable") as String)
println(mail.email)
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException:
>   JSONObject["deliverable"] is not a JSONObject.

I understand the error, it's because I do not have a name to the object, how can I directly take the fields?

**SOLVED:**

```
val jsonObj = JSONObject(jSonString.substring(jSonString.indexOf("{"), jSonString.lastIndexOf("}") + 1))

            val mail: String = jsonObj.get("deliverable").toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the keys you're using don't refer to nested objects inside your top level JSON object, you should use methods other than `getJSONObject` to access them.

For example, for the `deliverable` field, which is a boolean value:

```
val deliverable: Boolean = jsonObj.getBoolean("deliverable")
```

Or for the `address` field, a string:

```
val address: String = jsonObj.getString("address")
```

---

The valid use case for `getJSONObject` would be when you have a nested object like this:

```
{
    "nested": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

Here you could do `jsonObj.getJSONObject("nested").getString("foo")`, for example.